# Passing multiple Raster layers from C# to ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, modelbuilder, c#

I have created a model in ModelBuilder and I need to pass a list of rasters from my code (C#) but until now, ModelBuilder gets only the first record in the array.

I have been passing it in different ways like:

```
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
parameters.Add(lstRoots);//lstRoots is a list of strings with the root of the raster.
```

Other way:

```
foreach (string r in lstRoots) //lstRoots is a list of strings with the root of the raster.
{
   parameters.Add(r);
}
```

And another way:

```
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
IVariantArray paramlist = new VarArrayClass();

foreach (string r in lstRoots) 
{
   paramList.Add(r);

}
parameters.Add(paramList);
result = (IGeoProcessorResult)GP.Execute("ModelCellStatistics", parameters, null);
```

In the model I have created a variable that is the parameter with multiple values:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solved using layers.name!